# How do I list all the columns in a table?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

For the various popular database systems, how do you list all the columns in a table?

Comment: Here is the response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739203/oracle-query-to-fetch-column-names/8739400

Answer (score 362):

For MySQL, use:

```
DESCRIBE name_of_table;
```

This also works for Oracle as long as you are using SQL*Plus, or Oracle's SQL Developer.

Comment: This solution is for MYSQL not MSSQL

Comment: @dmvianna I don't think that necessarily applies to all of Oracle, but to SQL*Plus.

Comment: It should be `DESCRIBE `name_of_table``;

Comment: for sqlite - use:  pragma table_info(table_name) i.e. sqlite> pragma table_info(column1);

Comment: Editing, since `DESCRIBE` is not an Oracle PLSQL instruction but [a SQL*Plus command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm), and as such it doesn't work in most SQL IDEs.

Answer (score 164):

For MS SQL Server:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tableName'
```

Comment: The column of interest here would be COLUMN_NAME.

Comment: This should work on many DBMSs. `information_schema.columns` system view is part of  `ANSI SQL` standard ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)).

Comment: good answer but to avoid duplicates I would use: `select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tableName' and  table_schema = 'databaseName'`

Comment: This is SQL-92 ANSI compliant, and ought to work in all database engines.

Answer (score 154):

For Oracle (PL/SQL)

```
SELECT column_name
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'myTableName'
```

For MySQL

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name
```

Comment: Youd probably want to order the Oracle query by column_id

Comment: For Oracle is valid also `DESCRIBE name_of_table`.

Comment: use <database_name>;
show columns in <table_name> like '<column_prefix>%';  Will let you list only the columns starting with the prefix specified. Omitting the angle brackets of course.

Comment: what is `user_tab_cols` in your query?

Comment: @Jogi - Google "oracle user_tab_cols" - its built-in to Oracle db.

Comment: Note that it is possible for Oracle to see a column like `SYS_NC00064$` appear in your result. When you create an index on a table, the database automatically adds system-generated columns to the table to support indexing and searching. These columns are preceded by SYS_NC followed by a numeric value. You could filter those out by adding `AND column_name not like 'SYS%'` to the query.

Answer (score 63):

(5 years laters, for the Honor of PostgreSQL, the most advanced DDBB of the Kingdom)

In PostgreSQL:

```
\d table_name
```

Or, using SQL:

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where table_name = 'table_name';
```

Comment: should be \d table_name.  \dt table_name lists the relations.

Comment: The second query also works for ms sql. I used it because it added two more important variables that I wanted over the answer for [ms sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580487/7576836).

Answer (score 42):

I know it's late but I use this command for Oracle:

```
select column_name,data_type,data_length from all_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME = 'xxxx' AND OWNER ='xxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739203/oracle-query-to-fetch-column-names/8739400#8739400

Comment: I tried this in Oracle and it didn't work. The column_name was printed but nothing else. I had to use SELECT CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS CHAR(40)) || '  ' || DATA_TYPE to get a nice format and obtain multiple columns with concatenation.

Comment: if query returns empty, try using upper, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364929/5691498

Answer (score 32):

SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    c.name 
FROM
    sys.objects o
INNER JOIN
    sys.columns c
ON
    c.object_id = o.object_id
AND o.name = 'Table_Name'
```

or

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME  = 'Table_Name'
```

The second way is an ANSI standard and therefore *should* work on *all* ANSI compliant databases.

Comment: Neither of these work as written (or at least implied, as I read it) for MS SQL Server.  In both cases the table name column stores the name _without_ any `[` `]` around it, so the query must not use them, only the plain table name.  If that was not the OP's intention, at least be aware of this.

Comment: @JonBrave - that's correct, the square brackets were there to imply _"insert your table name here"_ :)

Comment: Being square brackets, I read it as the "_insert your table name inside square brackets (because of potentially reserved word) here_", and then got no matches :)  Perhaps BNF `<Table Name>` would have avoided the ambiguity.  Anyway, I realised you might have intended that as I wrote the comment --- it does no harm to warn others just in case.

Comment: Only works for MSSQL if there is no '[ ]' and the quotes ' ' are needed around the table name.

Answer (score 22):

Call below code in **MS SQL Server**:

```
sp_columns [tablename]
```

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2:

In a query editor, if you highlight the text of table name (ex dbo.MyTable) and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, you'll get a list of column names, type, length, etc.

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while you've highlighted `dbo.MyTable` is the equivalent of running `EXEC sp_help 'dbo.MyTable'` [according to this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx)

I can't get the variations on querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to work, so I use this instead.

Comment: Did not work in SSMS 2012. Btw did  you mean SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Comment: Yep, more precisely I meant Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2. I'll edit.

Answer (score 7):

For SQL Server

```
sp_help tablename
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a slight correction on the others in SQL Server (schema prefix is becoming more important!):

```
SELECT name
  FROM sys.columns 
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tablename');
```

Comment: Aaron, 
Thanks for adding this option to the list. Previously I was using this code. 
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME  = 'Table_Name'

However, it doesn’t always work. Especially on very large tables, like 50 million rows or more. Not sure why.
Your option works just great on all the tables I have tried so far. 
Thanks, and kudos.

Answer (score 3):

**SQL Server**

To list all the user defined tables of a database:

```
use [databasename]
select name from sysobjects where type = 'u'
```

To list all the columns of a table:

```
use [databasename]
select name from syscolumns where id=object_id('tablename')
```

Comment: Heh? This is just wrong...you can only use USE for databases...And the query returns all user defined tables in the database, which is not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
select Table_name as [Table] , column_name as [Column] , Table_catalog as [Database], table_schema as [Schema]  from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'dbo'
order by Table_name,COLUMN_NAME
```

Just my code

Answer (score 0):

**AWS Athena**

To list all columns from a table you can use:

```
SHOW COLUMNS {FROM|IN} database_name.table_name
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS {FROM|IN} table_name [{FROM|IN} database_name]
```

The FROM and IN keywords can be used interchangeably.

[AWS Athena doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-columns.html)