# Oracle query to fetch column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a mySQL query to get columns from a table like this:

```
String sqlStr="select column_name 
from information_schema.COLUMNS 
where table_name='users' 
and table_schema='"+_db+"' 
and column_name not in ('password','version','id')"
```

How do I change the above query in Oracle 11g database? I need to get columns names as a resultset for table 'users' excluding certain columns, specifying a schema. Right now I have all tables in my new tablespace, so do I specify tablespace name in place of schema name?

Also is there a generic HQL for this? In my new Oracle database (I am new to Oracle), I only have tablespace name, so is that equivalent to schema name (logically?)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The Oracle equivalent for `information_schema.COLUMNS` is `USER_TAB_COLS` for tables owned by the current user, `ALL_TAB_COLS` or `DBA_TAB_COLS` for tables owned by all users.

Tablespace is not equivalent to a schema, neither do you have to provide the tablespace name.

Providing the schema/username would be of use if you want to query `ALL_TAB_COLS` or `DBA_TAB_COLS` for columns OF tables owned by a specific user. in your case, I'd imagine the query would look something like:

```
String sqlStr= "
SELECT column_name
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE table_name = 'USERS'
   AND owner = '" +_db+ "'
   AND column_name NOT IN ( 'PASSWORD', 'VERSION', 'ID' )"
```

Note that with this approach, you risk SQL injection.

**EDIT:** Uppercased the table- and column names as these are typically uppercase in Oracle; they are only lower- or mixed case if created with double quotes around them.

Comment: by the way I found a generic way of doing this irrespective of the databbase through jdbc .. with the link here : http://www.kodejava.org/examples/163.html

Comment: I also had to add `and virtual_column = 'NO'` to my query.

Answer (score 123):

The below query worked for me in Oracle database.

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='MyTableName';
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Oracle is case-sensitive.  I typically use `...WHERE LOWER(Table_Name) = 'mytablename';`.

Comment: @user565869 I'd use `where lower(TABLE_NAME) = lower('WHATEVER')`, else when the table name has some uppercase character it won't find the table either

Comment: `SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE UPPER(Table_Name) = UPPER('tablename');` works just as well.

Comment: Using `lower(TABLE_NAME)` or `upper(TABLE_NAME)` requires oracle to do a table scan of the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` table to get all values of `TABLE_NAME` before it can compare it to the supplied `UPPER('MyTableName')`. In quick testing this made the performance unusable for my purpose so I will stick with case sensitive comparisons.

Comment: Oracle stores object names in uppercase. Take advantage of that fact. If you need to "translate" the case, translate the case of the user input - not the Oracle object name. I.e. `WHERE table_name = UPPER('my_table_name')`. If this is part of a larger piece of code, you should uppercase the user input _before_ passing it to the WHERE condition.

Answer (score 46):

in oracle you can use

```
desc users
```

to display all columns containing in users table

Comment: ... because although it represents an answer to 'how to get a list of all the columns of a table', it does not answer the question that was asked: 1) it's not a query, 2) it doesn't limit/filter the columns returned, 3) is it returning a result set?

Comment: Lack of upvotes doesn't make `desc users` a bad answer to some questions, but it is not a good answer to _this one_.

Comment: and because its not a sql query, rather it's sql* plus command. checkout this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133666/what-is-the-reason-for-not-working-of-describe-command-on-oracle

Answer (score 8):

You may try this : ( It works on 11g and it returns all column name from a table , here test_tbl is the table name and user_tab_columns are user permitted table's columns )

```
select  COLUMN_NAME  from user_tab_columns
where table_name='test_tbl';
```

Comment: `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` is actually the columns of the tables owned by the user, not those of tables permitted to the user.

Answer (score 6):

the point is that in toad u have to write table name capital, like this:

```
select *
FROM all_tab_columns
where table_name like 'IDECLARATION';
```

Answer (score 2):

The query to use with Oracle is:

`String sqlStr="select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='"+_db+".users' and COLUMN_NAME not in ('password','version','id')"`

Never heard of HQL for such queries. I assume it doesn't make sense for ORM implementations to deal with it. ORM is an Object Relational Mapping, and what you're looking for is metadata mapping... You wouldn't use HQL, rather use API methods for this purpose, or direct SQL. For instance, you can use JDBC [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html).

I think tablespace has nothing to do with schema. AFAIK tablespaces are mainly used for logical internal technical purposes which should bother DBAs. For more information regarding tablespaces, see [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm).

Comment: `TABLE_NAME='"+_db+".users'` will fail; you need to separate owner/schema and table name in `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I was able to get the column names was using the following query:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
FROM all_tab_columns atc
WHERE table_name like 'USERS'
```

Answer (score 2):

On Several occasions, we would need comma separated list of all the columns from a table in a schema. In such cases we can use this generic function which fetches the comma separated list as a string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cols(
    p_schema_name IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name  IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME , ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY ROWNUM )
  INTO v_string
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE OWNER    = p_schema_name
  AND table_name = p_table_name;
  RETURN v_string;
END;
/
```

So, simply calling the function from the query yields a row with all the columns.

```
select cols('HR','EMPLOYEES') FROM DUAL;

EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID
```

**Note:** `LISTAGG` will fail if the combined length of all columns exceed `4000` characters which is rare. For most cases , this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I find this one useful in Oracle:

```
SELECT 
    obj.object_name, 
    atc.column_name, 
    atc.data_type, 
    atc.data_length 
FROM 
    all_tab_columns atc,
    (SELECT 
        * 
     FROM 
         all_objects
     WHERE 
        object_name like 'GL_JE%'
        AND owner = 'GL'
        AND object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW')   
    ) obj
WHERE 
    atc.table_name = obj.object_name
ORDER BY 
    obj.object_name, 
    atc.column_name;
```

Comment: What if there are multiple tables with the same name, but different owners?

Answer (score 0):

1. `SELECT * FROM <SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME> WHERE ROWNUM = 0;` --> Note that, this is Query Result, a ResultSet. This is exportable to other formats.
   And, you can export the **Query Result** to `Text` format. Export looks like below when I did `SELECT * FROM SATURN.SPRIDEN WHERE ROWNUM = 0;` :

   "SPRTELE_PIDM"  "SPRTELE_SEQNO" "SPRTELE_TELE_CODE" "SPRTELE_ACTIVITY_DATE" "SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA"    "SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER"  "SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT" "SPRTELE_STATUS_IND"    "SPRTELE_ATYP_CODE" "SPRTELE_ADDR_SEQNO"    "SPRTELE_PRIMARY_IND"   "SPRTELE_UNLIST_IND"    "SPRTELE_COMMENT"   "SPRTELE_INTL_ACCESS"   "SPRTELE_DATA_ORIGIN"   "SPRTELE_USER_ID"   "SPRTELE_CTRY_CODE_PHONE"   "SPRTELE_SURROGATE_ID"  "SPRTELE_VERSION"   "SPRTELE_VPDI_CODE"
2. `DESCRIBE <TABLE_NAME>`  --> Note: This is script output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below query to get a list of table names which uses the specific column in DB2:

```
SELECT TBNAME                
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS       
WHERE NAME LIKE '%COLUMN_NAME';
```

Note : Here replace the `COLUMN_NAME` with the column name that you are searching for.

Comment: Perhaps you should look for DB2 questions to answer? I doubt someone searching for Oracle would need a DB2 answer.

Comment: This answer actually helped me.  I'm using DB2 in Oracle mode and it doesn't support all_tab_cols.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

describe 'Table Name'

It will return all column names and data types