# How to find a table name which's column name consist cl_

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I have a oracle **10G** data base and I want to find all the table name of which column name consist `cl_` Is there any way to find all the table name I tried `all_objects` and `all_source` But failed. Please suggest some way to find them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle query to fetch column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739203/oracle-query-to-fetch-column-names)

Comment: @alfasin no sir The query is little tricky Actualy I want to find any sollution through which I can rename a column name `cl_` to `ol_` but I am getting error message.

Comment: We don't know what is bigger picture about your question.. If you can explain brief then we can try to find ans for that.

Comment: If you're getting an error msg you should explain exactly what you're doing and what's the error. Our psychic abilities are limited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALL_TAB_COLS` would give you the required details.

For example, I add a new table `T` to SCOTT schema, with column name as `EMP_ID`, I expect only 1 row in output for column name `like 'EMP_%'`

Let's see -

**Edit** Forgot to `ESCAPE` underscore.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(EMP_ID NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name
  2  FROM all_tab_cols
  3  WHERE owner='SCOTT'
  4  AND column_name LIKE 'EMP\_%' ESCAPE '\';

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- --------------
T                    EMP_ID

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query in oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like upper('%cl\_%') escape '\';
```

Answer (score 0):

all_tab_cols contains the details of all columns of tables owned by all users.

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE UPPER(column_name) like UPPER('%cl\_%') ESCAPE '\';--Returns details of all column names which has 'cl_' in its name

SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE UPPER(column_name) like UPPER('cl\_%') ESCAPE '\';--Returns details of all column names which start with 'cl_' in its name

SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE UPPER(column_name) like UPPER('%cl\_') ESCAPE '\';--Returns details of all column names which end with 'cl_' in its name
```

You can also try DBA_TAB_COLS.

**Note :** You can also use USER_TAB_COLS but it only returns the details of the columns of a table owned by the current user.

Hope this helps...!!!