# How do I get all table names and its column names in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How do I get all table names and its column names in oracle?  The Table names should be printed first followed by all the column name, then the next table and its columns, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle query to fetch column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739203/oracle-query-to-fetch-column-names)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dba you can see all tables in DB;

```
select * from all_tab_columns
order by table_name;
```

Comment: This will generate a lot of unneeded information (`select *` is very rarely needed). It also does not present the results in the **order** requested.

Answer (score 0):

The query below, in the middle column (`str`), has the data the way you requested it. However, without the info in the first and/or the last column, it is not clear how you will know which values are table names and which are columns under them.

It would make a lot more sense to have table name in one column (repeated for each of its columns), then the column name and then the order. This would be just the second member of the `union all` operation.

The query below works for the tables in your schema. If you want to do this for all the tables you have access to, use `all_tables` and `all_tab_columns`; if you have DBA privileges, use `dba_tables` and `dba_tab_columns` (but in these cases, don't you need to know the schema/owner, not just the table name?)

```
select table_name as tbl, table_name as str, 0 as ord from user_tables
union all
select table_name, column_name, column_id from user_tab_columns
order by tbl, ord
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM all_tab_cols
order by table_name, column_name
```