# Query a table and a column name stored in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I come here because of a problem that I am not experienced enough to solve, in an Oracle Database. Let me explain:

### The tables

I have a table that we'll call **Attributes**, containing 3 columns : 
***ID***, the id of the attribute, **-EDIT: Entity_ID as well, the entity it refers to /EDIT-**, ***Table_name***, containing the name of the table in which the value of the attribute is stored, and ***Column_name***, containing the name of the column in that table in which is the value is stored.

Every tables referenced in the column ***Table_name***, contains the same column names (such as *Value1*,*Value2*, etc..) except for the first one that references another entity (***Entity_id***), to which the attribute is linked to.

### What I am looking for

My goal is to build a query that selects every attribute (based on its id) and its value. But what I don't know is how to query that since the name of table and of the column changes. 
Is there a way to use variables? But if so, how can I put them in the query so that it automatically changes for each row?

**EDIT**

### EXAMPLE

```
ATTRIBUTES table
ID         ENTITY_ID      TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME
---------- -------------- ------------ -----------
1          3              Values_A     Value_1  
2          2              Values_B     Value_3
3          2              Values_A     Value_2

VALUES_A table
ENTITY_ID  Value_1        Value_2      Value_3
---------- -------------- ------------ -----------
1          Monday         42           Green
2          Sunday         3000         Blue
3          Wednesday      1            Black

VALUES_B table
ENTITY_ID  Value_1        Value_2      Value_3
---------- -------------- ------------ ------------
1          Tuesday        26           Green
2          Saturday       3            Red
3          Wednesday      15           White
```

So the result I'm looking for would be:

```
RESULT:
ID        Value
--------- -----------
1         Wednesday
2         Red
3         3000
```

Sorry if this is painful to watch, it was as painful to make (didn't find how to format it better)

Comment: can you share the actual DDL for ATTRIBUTES as well as sample data and what you want your output to look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739203/oracle-query-to-fetch-column-names or http://onewebsql.com/blog/list-all-tables

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I can't share it since it's a bit sensitive data and it wouldn't help since I tried to simplify the situation as best as I could describing only the (biggest) problem I am dealing with.
The output should look like a simple query result, such as 
`SELECT ID, Entity_ID, Value from TABLE` if TABLE was a simple table that just stored the value instead of storing the location of the said

Comment: @CaptainIK then make up some fake rows - make it easier for us to help you and you'll increase your odds ten-fold of getting actionable answers

Comment: @cSteusloff 
So what you're suggesting me would be to fetch all the tables in my database and do like a join based on the name I have stored in Attributes' column Table_name?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith 
Okay, incoming

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Done. Let me just specify that I didn't chose this type of data architecture ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Peter M's query to build the SQL text, and then harnessing the dark power of XML:

```
create table attributes (id, entity_id, table_name, column_name)
as
select 1, 3, 'VALUES_A', 'VALUE_1' from dual union all
select 2, 2, 'VALUES_B', 'VALUE_3' from dual union all
select 3, 2, 'VALUES_A', 'VALUE_2' from dual;

create table values_a (entity_id, value_1, value_2, value_3)
as
select 1, 'Monday', 42, 'Green' from dual union all
select 2, 'Sunday', 3000, 'Blue' from dual union all
select 3, 'Wednesday', 1, 'Black' from dual;

create table values_b (entity_id, value_1, value_2, value_3)
as
select 1, 'Tuesday', 26, 'Green' from dual union all
select 2, 'Saturday', 3, 'Red' from dual union all
select 3, 'Wednesday', 15, 'White' from dual;
```

Query:

```
with queries as
     ( select table_name, column_name, entity_id
            , 'select '|| column_name || ' as c from ' || table_name ||
             ' where entity_id = ' || entity_id ||
              case
                  when id = max_id then ''
                  else ' union all '
              end as sqltext
       from 
           ( select a.*, max(a.id) over (order by id) max_id from attributes a ) )
select table_name, column_name, entity_id
     , extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(sqltext)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C') as sql_result
from   queries;
```

Results:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME  ENTITY_ID SQL_RESULT
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------
VALUES_A   VALUE_1              3 Wednesday
VALUES_B   VALUE_3              2 Red
VALUES_A   VALUE_2              2 3000
```

Comment: Thank you very much (and @Peter M for the basis of it) for your answer! It works perfectly fine on the example. Now all I have to do is to adapt it to my problem (that includes multiple joins but that should be alright). I didn't know anything about using xml like this, and this "with _ as __ select ", I think I'll look into this for the future. Thanks again !

Comment: I should add that [`extractvalue` is deprecated as of 11gR2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/changes.htm#ADXDB-GUID-4D46D8F7-2ACC-49D5-863D-7F16BF84EBCD), but I'm afraid I don't know enough XML to be able to change it to the currently favoured syntax. The manual suggests `XMLTable` or `XMLCast` and `XMLQuery`, but those are not drop-in replacements and would thus seem to be less useful than the deprecated function, but that's XML for you.

Answer (score 2):

this is ugly

but it would generate a sql statement that you could run, maybe it is not what you want

```
select 'select '|| column_name || ' from ' || table_name || ' where entity_id = ' || entity_id || case when id = max_id then '' else ' union all ' end
from 
  (select a.*, max(a.id) over (order by id) max_id 
   from attributes a)
```

Comment: Ok, this seems like it could work! But how can I run this statement then?

Comment: run this sql (in sql developer or toad or something) -- then get the result, it will be another sql statement -- run that result in another window in sql developer and hopefully it will give you want you want

Comment: When I run this on SQL developer, the result is a table and on each row there's a query, and I have absolutely no idea how to run it again in order to make the final result table?

Comment: just select every row -- then copy, then paste it into the worksheet -- each row is a query but see how there is a union all at the end, that will make all of them together one big sql statement