# How to query select table with column names mapped in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I have two tables: `dataTable` and `dataTableColNames`.

`dataTable` goes like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | col9
-----|------|------|-----|-----------
123  | abcd | text | ... | 02/02/2018
 ... | ...  | ...  | ... | ...
999  | xyz  | text | ... | 31/12/2018
```

and has about 30 rows.

`dataTableColNames` is something like this:

```
colID | colNameEn       | colNameRu
------|-----------------|--------------
col1  | "Column 1 Name" | "Колонка 1"
...   | ...             | ...
col9  | "Column 9 Name" | "Колонка 9"
```

and could contain column names even 5 or more words long. Also, there could be different translations for column titles for the same data.

How to make a `SELECT` query to get a table like this?

```
Column 1 name | ... | Column 9 Name
--------------|-----|--------------
123           | ... | 02/02/2018
```

PL/SQL Developer v10

This question is not quite duplicate because my tables do not have anything like `entity_id` nor any foreign keys. Also, it is about column aliases, not querying different values from many different tables. Or is it? Anyway, I don't see a solution for my problem in answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001004/query-a-table-and-a-column-name-stored-in-a-table). Or maybe don't understand. How to implement it on my problem?

Comment: It is pointless to have a table dataTableColNames just to store column aliases. Basically, you  can select them  simply as `select col1 as "Column 1 Name", col2 as "Column 2 Name"  .. `

Comment: What if i have much more columns? Or names are very long - like, about a sentence.

Comment: Even then it would be a very bad design. You may eventually get a solution here from someone, but it would be  pointless to perform all that operation ( probably  with Unpivot and Pivot) just to show aliases. Personally, I'm reluctant to spend my time just to give someone such a solution. anyways, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks anyway. GLHF) Would like to know which DB design with long column names and translations could be better.

Comment: I can see the advantages of this design–it's flexible and dynamic and enables arbitrary column name values to be stored as data rather than being hardcoded into sql

Answer (score 1):

A solution you might try is to `UNION` two queries together, the first being from `dataTableColNames` and the second from `dataTable`. The first query uses a subquery which joins `dataTableColNames` to itself for each column, and then the outer query serves to pivot the column name rows into columns.  The second query returns the data.  The query below is *untested*.  You will also need to use either your sql tool to suppress the column name headers (`col1, col2, col3`) returned to the console or gui, or post-process the results to do so in your client or middleware.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM (
 SELECT c1.col1Name as col1, c2.col2Name as col2, c3.col3Name as col3
   FROM dataTableColNames c1
   JOIN dataTableColNames c2 on c1.colId = c2.colId
   JOIN dataTableColNames c3 on c1.colId = c3.colId
  WHERE c1.colId = 'col1'
    AND c2.colId = 'col2'
    AND c3.colId = 'col3' 
) t1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from dataTable
```