# How to get column names from a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, talend

I have a specific query with joins and aliases, and I need to retrieve columns name for a REST request in Talend.

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 6.2 and I've got an Oracle 11g database with a read-only account. I can execute scripts with Talend, For example the query:

```sql
select 
    u.name as "user", 
    f.name as "food", 
    e.rate 
from 
    Users as u 
    join Eval as e on u.user_id = e.user_id 
    join Food as f on e.food_id = f.food_id
where
    1 = 1
```

should give the following result:

```
+------+--------+------+
| user | food   | rate |
+------+--------+------+
| Baba | Donuts | 16.0 |
| Baba | Cheese | 20.0 |
| Keke | Pasta  | 12.5 |
| Keke | Cheese | 15.0 |
+------+--------+------+
```

And I try to get the columns (in the right order) as follows by using scripts or Talend:

```
+--------+
| Column |
+--------+
| user   |
| food   |
| rate   |
+--------+
```

Is there a way to query the Oracle database to get the columns or using talend to retrieve them?

### UPDATE

Thanks to Marmite Bomber, a duplicate has been identified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345133/how-to-get-column-names-of-a-hypothetical-table-returned-by-a-query-oracle-sql/55345654#55345654) for the Oracle approach. Now we need a Talend approach to the problem.

Comment: See the answer to the duplicated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345654/4808122) you may use either `DBMS_SQL` or `JDBC` approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this on a tJavaRow, following your DBInput component :

```
for (java.lang.reflect.Field field: row1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
context.columnName = field.getName();
      System.out.println("Field name is " + context.columnName );      
           }
```

Spotted on talend help center here : https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/resolved-how-to-get-the-column-names-in-a-data-flow/td-p/99172

You can extend this, and put the column list on your outputflow :

```
//add this inside the loop, and 'columnNames' as an output row in tJavaRow schema

             output_row.columnNames+=context.columnName+";";
```

With a tNormalize after tJavaRow, you shoud get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly, I also add a "rownum = 1" in the where clause for performance purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

Here´s a link to an oracle community thread which should answer your question

[community.oracle.com](https://community.oracle.com/thread/207510?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: It's usefull if we want columns from a table but in my query I've multiple tables and I don't want all the columns from all the tables, just the selected ones

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to write a comment, so posting this as an answer:

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE table_name = 'table_name_here'
```

Comment: Sorry yoga, your answer isn't correct. With your request you can only get the column from a defined table. With your approach to answer the question, you should create a temporary table based on the request and then select the columns names. The problem is I can't write on the database for security requirements.