# How to get column names of table at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Lets say I have a table in SQLServer named MyTable

```
ID FirstName   LastName
1  Harry       Dan
2  Maria       Vicente
3  Joe         Martin
```

Now if I have to insert any data in table, I will simply fire Insert Query like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (4, Smith, Dan);
```

But what if I don't know the column names beforehand, I only know table name. Then is there a way to get the column name of table at runtime?

Comment: You are inserting data into tables that you don't know the structure until runtime? Sounds like a bad scenario IMHO.

Comment: @Jake1164, this is quite common for fully disconnected systems. Consider an example where you have a centralized data store that is used as a facilitator to share data between geographically dispersed services that you know nothing about. Now consider you could send an object, leverage its properties, and build an `INSERT` statement for a table you know nothing about - all you know is that the properties match the schema and that the table is **supposed** to be there. ***In short, I can think of more scenarios where you wouldn't know about the schema.***

Comment: In addition to all the answers about querying system metadata, if you prefer a 'pure' .NET solution then you could use an [SMO `Table` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220470.aspx) and examine the `Columns` collection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use sql-

```
SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TABLE_NAME')
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can query for `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM TableName`. Then, you can get the columns:

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    reader.Read();
    var table = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option using pure C# / .NET code:
First a helper method, that here returns a simple list of column names.  Using a DataTable to hold table schema information, means that other information can also be retreived for each column, fx. if it is an AutoIncreament column etc.

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetColumnNames(string conStr, string tableName)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            var sqlCmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from " + tableName + " where 1=0";  // No data wanted, only schema
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            var sqlDR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            var dataTable = sqlDR.GetSchemaTable();

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) result.Add(row.Field<string>("ColumnName"));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The method can be called as:

```
        var sortedNames = GetColumnNames("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=OF2E;Integrated Security=SSPI", "Articles").OrderBy(x => x);
        foreach (var columnName in sortedNames) Console.WriteLine(columnName);
```

Comment: Seems like people have a hard time noticing, that the question for a C# solution and not a SQL answer (though, it is a bit confusing, as the question includes some SQL code) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply by this Query :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.[table_name]')
```

OR This Query :

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = [table_name]
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ColName = "";
        var model = new AttributeMappingSource().GetModel(typeof(DataClassesDataContext));
        foreach (var mt in model.GetTables())
        {
            if (mt.TableName == "dbo.Table_Name")
            {
                foreach (var dm in mt.RowType.DataMembers)
                {
                    ColName = dm.MappedName + ", ";
                    Response.Write(ColName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This question was answered before in various threads

check:

[How can I get column names from a table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/get-columns-of-a-table-sql-server)

[How can I get column names from a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452464/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table)

[How do I list all the columns in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580450/how-do-i-list-all-the-columns-in-a-table)