# Oracle SQL: selecting from all_tab_columns does not find existing column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I run the following query:

```
select count(*) from all_tab_columns
        where column_name = 'foo'
        and table_name = 'VIEW0';
```

I get 0 for a result. I expect 1.

But if I run the following query I get many (expected) rows returned:

```
select foo from VIEW0;
```

Why? I'm assuming I'm making some dumb syntax mistake or my understanding is way off.

Comment: Shouldn't the value you are searching for in column_name be uppercase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the reason is that you have case sensitive setting.

Try to add `UPPER` function as below.

```
select count(*) from all_tab_columns
        where column_name = upper('foo')
        and table_name = 'VIEW0';
```

Comment: Oracle always store column names as well as table names in upper case; so upper is necessary on 'foo'

Comment: Thanks! That was it!  I will vote it in 4 minutes when I am allowed to.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I've change the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The upper on column_name and table_name are unneeded and really the other two uppers are unneeded as one is already all uppercase and its easy to just change the the other one to uppercase and not have to do any work on the system to change the case.

Comment: Wait is there a difference between accepting the answer and voting for it?

Comment: @lostinthebits Yes! You can accept only one and only answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

[ALL_TAB_COLUMNS describes the columns of the tables, views, and clusters **accessible** to the current user.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm) Check, if user under whom you running this query have access to the desired table.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, at least in 11g, that you cannot access the data dictionary tables from PL/SQL.  Running any select on all_tab_columns inside PL/SQL always returns no results.  Attempting to access dba_tab_columns will not compile, because the compiler believes the table (or view) does not exist.

I'd love to see how to access the data dictionary from PL/SQL.