# Stopping OracleBulkCopy to ignore/disable primary key

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

Is there a way to stop OracleBulkCopy to ignore/disable primary key (unique-constraints on not-null columns). At the moment when inserting a batch which contains duplicated rows, the destination table becomes problematic that is causing the indices to go in unusable state.

Therefore, OracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer will refuse to run again if the index starts in an UNUSABLE state.

```
Using bulkCopy As OracleBulkCopy = New OracleBulkCopy(conBsdOracle, OracleBulkCopyOptions.Default
End Using
```

Comment: Did you try [array binding](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10961_01/features.htm#1025579)?

Comment: @Neolisk I haven't because I do not want to be column-committed since there are frequent additions in the table column structure.

Comment: You can build a dynamic query with [user_tab_cols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580450/how-do-i-list-all-the-columns-in-a-table).