# List all columns of a query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a SQL stmt in Oracle that lets me extract all the columns a query returns?

In conjunction with Java I could execute the query and process the metadata but I look for a handy way.

Comment: You should know them, because you have specified the query. Don't use `*`. Be explicit.

Comment: Not necessarily: What if I use the following query? `SELECT * FROM TBL_A A, TBL_B B WHERE A.ID = B.ID`

Comment: See here how to list the columns of a table: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26977159/402322

Comment: If you explain a little more how you plan on using this, or even better, if you can provide some code of where you need this, you may get an answer better suited to your needs. For instance, is it possible that you are looking for a way of getting this information using the JDBC API?

Comment: I have very lengthy SQL stmts and I want to get the fetched columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DECLARE 

    sqlstr VARCHAR2(1000);
    cur INTEGER;
    columnCount INTEGER;
    describeColumns DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;

BEGIN 

    cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    sqlstr := 'SELECT * FROM TBL_A A, TBL_B B WHERE A.ID = B.ID';
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, sqlStr, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(cur, columnCount, describeColumns);   
    FOR i IN 1..columnCount LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( describeColumns(i).col_name );
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

END;
```

**Update:** In order to get a result set you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetColumns(sqlstr IN VARCHAR2) 
   RETURN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE PIPELINED AS

    cur INTEGER;
    columnCount INTEGER;
    describeColumns DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;

BEGIN 

    cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, sqlStr, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(cur, columnCount, describeColumns);   
    FOR i IN 1..columnCount LOOP
        PIPE ROW(describeColumns(i).col_name);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
   RETURN;
END;


SELECT * FROM TABLE(GetColumns('SELECT * FROM TBL_A A, TBL_B B WHERE A.ID = B.ID'));
```

Comment: Don't forget to execute `set serveroutput on` in SQL dev

Comment: Is there also a way to return the values of `describeColumns` as a result set?